# Using boost::iterator_range in Natural Language Processing

Tags: c++, regex, boost, nlp, boost-iterators

My Problem is related to Natural Language Processing (NLP) and the chunking of input strings into logical groups.

To simplify things what I have is a vector of Token data structures, each of which contains a 'tag' string value among other things.

```
class Token
{
   public:
      std::string tag;
      std::string word;
      // other stuff;
};

std::vector<Token> input_tokens;
typedef std::vector<Token>::iterator tok_iter;
```

I also form a concatenated string of 'tag' values taken from each Token in the vector that looks like this:

```
std::string pos_tags = "DT JJ NN NN IN RB JJ NN DT";
```

I am interested in forming chunkings of JJ (adjective) and NN (noun) instances only so that for the 
above pos_tags example there would be two matching chunks:

"JJ NN NN",  "JJ NN"

Is it possible to run a kind of regex over the pos_tags string such that each regex match represents the range of tokens in the input token set (input_tokens) from where it came?   In other words, each chunk formed is not a string, but represented by a start/end iterators.

Ideally I would like to store the matches I have found as a vector of boost::iterator_range, where each range represents the start/end of each chunk found, something like this:

```
std::vector< boost::iterator_range<tok_iter> > chunks;
```

I hope this makes sense.  I am not necessarily looking for the complete code, but hints as to how to use regular expressions (I'm a novice) in this way.

Comment: I see the "just use `std::vector`" comments coming...

Comment: I don't quite understand how you want to use regular expressions.  You can think of chunking patterns as regular expressions over an alphabet of part-of-speech tags, rather than over an alphabet of characters.  C++ strings are templated, so you can use non-character types in them, and the regular expression library would still work.  Is this what you want to do?  Based on some other parts of your question I'm guessing not, but I still don't quite understand what you're going for.

Comment: Actually, looking at this it does not necessarily have to use regular expressions, I was thinking that maybe regexes would be a neat way of finding the matches.  Ultimately I need to find some way of storing each chunk I find, but not stored as a string, but as iterators representing each chunk's start/end iterator position in the vector of Tokens

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstand, but I believe you are simply missing one additional data structure: A mapping that maps positions in the POS tag string to iterator positions in the original token vector. A simple `vector<tok_iter>`, of the same length as the POS tag string. Each entry would provide the `tok_iter` of the token that corresponds to that position. Using this data structure, it would be a quick operation to map the regex results to token iterators.

Comment: Hi jogopan that sounds close to what I'm trying to achieve.  The motivation for using boost::iterator_range is to provide iterator start/end positions.